# Windows Phone 7 Emulator runs in slow mode... even tho my system supports VT

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation

Windows Phone 7 Emulator runs in slow mode... even tho my system supports VT

I just updated my Sony Vaio FW21E's bios update, now VT is enabled, but emulator still runs in same old slow mode.

How can I run the emulator in VT mode.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your system meets the requirements laid out here.

[Setup and System Requirements for Windows Phone Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626524%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

In particular, verify your gpu is being recognised by the emualtor by checking the [frame rate counters](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/07/counters/) are visible.

This will not happen if your display driver is not WDDM1.1 compliant and minimum Directx 10.

I also recommend trying a Win7 install on a spare hard disk if you're running Vista. This consistently produces positive results when problems of this nature are reported on hardware compliant systems.

Comment: This. I'm unsure what "slow" is, but if you're seeing choppy graphics in the emulator it's 99% because of an unsupported GPU card. In that scenario all emulator rendering is done using software, without any hardware acceleration. You might have to upgrade your hardware.

Comment: The issue was the updated driver was not WDDM 1.1 compatible I just restored the driver to earlier version which was installed by MS. Which was 1.1 WDDM

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on my Mac running bootcamp. I read in some forum what appeared to be the weirdest solution ever.

If I had Netflix open, **streaming a movie**, my emulator would work perfectly. When I did not, it would just be the slowest thing.

I read somewhere that could be related to drivers and hardware acceleration. So Windows Phone was not 'hardcore' enough to trigger turning on the acceleration on the video card but when you had the streaming ON it was using it, making it fast.

You might try that out... I know it sounds dumb but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The HD3450 should be ok as its a DirectX 10 card I beleive

As said above the card needs to be WDDM1.1

you can check this by running 'dxdiag' in the run or search box in vista. go to 'Display 1' (or just Dispaly) tab, and on the right there will be DDI Version - should be 10, and Driver Model - should be WDDM 1.1.

If its not compliant with WDDM1.1/DX10, it will work ok but you wont get things like aminmations on page transitions etc.

Comment: The issue was the updated driver was not WDDM 1.1 compatible I just restored the driver to earlier version which was installed by MS. Which was 1.1 WDDM.